# Server Tag not well formed with ASP:Button

Tags: asp.net

I have read through the various topics and found none that assisted me in my situation.

Based on whether it is 1 or 0 for my sold variable, i want to be able to show or hide a button accordingly.

I did the following but I am getting a server tag not well formed error and despite changing the quotes ' and " (which i knew wouldn't help), it still doesn't solve the error.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnMarkAsSold" OnClick="btnWantSell" runat="server" Text="Mark as sold" class="btn btn-warning btn-block higher bold" <%#(Eval("Sold").ToString() == "1" ? "style='display:none'" : String.Empty) %> />
<asp:Button ID="btnSold" runat="server" Text="SOLD" class="btn btn-danger btn-block higher bold" <%#(Eval("Sold").ToString() == "0" ? "style='display:none'" : String.Empty) %> />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested and below is working

The problem is `style=display:none`. Create a class like `hidden` and update your button as:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSold" runat="server" Text="SOLD" class='btn btn-danger btn-block higher bold <%#(Eval("Sold").ToString() == "0" ? "hidden" : String.Empty) %>'  />

<asp:Button ID="btnMarkAsSold" OnClick="btnWantSell" runat="server" Text="Mark as sold" class='btn btn-warning btn-block higher bold <%#(Eval("Sold").ToString() == "1" ? "hidden" : String.Empty) %>' />
```

**CSS**

```
hidden{ display:none;}
```

**Visible property**

To use `Visible` property of button as suggested in @Mahmood's answer

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSold" runat="server" Text="SOLD" class="btn btn-danger btn-block higher bold" Visible="<%# Eval("Sold").ToString() == "0" ? false : true %>" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not use inline server tag directly in a server control. However you can do so inside an attribute:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSold" runat="server" Text="SOLD" class="btn btn-danger btn-block higher bold" Visible="<%# Eval("Sold").ToString() == "0" ? false : true %>" />
<asp:Button ID="btnMarkAsSold" OnClick="btnWantSell" runat="server" Text="Mark as sold" class="btn btn-warning btn-block higher bold" Visible="<%#Eval("Sold").ToString() == "1" ? false : true %> />
```